# grails show image in the form from directory

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am saving user's image at the time of saving user info. At the time of showing the user info I want to show the user image. But it's only showing the url -- [web-app\images\userImages\bappi.jpeg] -- to my form. Can anyone please help me on this ? I am using grails 2.1.0. here is my code below :

my closure in controller >>

```
def userInfo = {
    def user = User.get(1)
    def userId = user.id
    def username = user.username
    def type = user.avatarType.substring(6)
    def fileName = username + "." + type
    def photo = new File( grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString() + File.separatorChar + fileName)

    [userId: userId, username:username, photo:photo]
}
```

my view page userInfo.gsp >>

```
<g:form controller="user" action="editUser">
       User Name : ${username} <br/>
       Photo : ${photo} <p></p>
    <g:hiddenField name="userId" id="userId" value="${userId}"/>
    <g:submitButton name="editUser" value="Edit" />
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
<g:img uri="${photo}"/>
```

Or you can try this:

```
 <g:img dir="path/to/image" file="imageFileName.extention"/>
```